# Create instance of an ASPX page programmatically and parse html

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

From the code on one page I want to be able to generate an instance of another page and parse the html from certain controls on that page.

this is what i have tried so far

```
var APIListPage = (APIList)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/APIHelp/APIList.aspx", typeof(APIList));
ParseHtml(APIListPage.pdfPage);
```

The problem is `APIListPage.pdfPage` is always `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call the page instance's "ProcessRequest" procedure, to let it experience a full Page LifeCycle. It won't load just by creating the instance.